# How to copy light effect from one file to another without losing properties in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I wanted to copy a light effect from a file that I download to my own file, but when I do it, the transparency and color of the thing I want to copy goes away. 
It is driving me insane by now.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: some images.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try with Illustrator Graphic Styles?

Comment: Well, I searched how to use that: I grabbed the effect onto the Graphic Styles, but it didn't work as I pasted it in my file and clicked on the Style. It's still with a white background. I don't know if I used it wrong, sorry if I did that.

Comment: Ok: I'm making a party flyer, and wanted to add some light effects in it, like a golden light effect (it's a gala party). So I downloaded a light effect file from the internet, but I don't know how to copy them and paste in my own file without it going more whitey and not "transparent". To add more details, in the original file it has a squared transparent background. I'm sorry I'm kind new to this!

Comment: I suppose the best it would to see some graphic example of what you are trying to do and what you get

Comment: It doesn't work in the new file because it's not on black. - i.e. there's no contrast like there is in the original file. You **might** try simply ignoring the previous art, and merely use the **Flare Tool** in Illustrator (it's under the rectangle tool) for the new art.

Comment: GUYS! My document was in CMYK color mode. Once I changed, it worked. Thanks everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 1):

I have in an earlier case checked the first of your images to see how it's built. The image was this: https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/light-effects-collection_1015001.htm

So, you wanted to copy the effect only, not whole shapes?

Forget it, you must be a vector graphics master or more preferably a clairvoyant to be able to explode those EPS files and to extract the light and color so that you can put them into your own shapes. Those files are extremely complex and obviously intentionally built to be complex to modify. They have multilevel groupings, -masking and group level blendings.

You can ungroup an image and extract say one sun shape, but you can in practice only place it onto a black backgroud and let it be. Any attempt to change the used shapes to your own shapes will end to a black unmanageable mess like this:

[image]

You should try something simpler. You can surely build the needed effects to your own shapes in an intuitive way if you work tutorials, practice and maybe ask help if you get stucked in a well specified detail.